# How to I import a table into wordpress Elementor Page Builder

Tags: wordpress, elementor

How to Copy Paste or import a table structure into word press Elementor Page Builder. The Elementor does not have table structure. I lose the styles when copied from excel sheet. It shows all th columns background as black.
I tired to do same in source tab, but the same.

I tried few plugins and still same. The wordpress default editor works but forced to use Elementor as it has more features included like carousel, gallery.

Tried few plugins related to Elementor, but the same.

Any workarounds, please.